# how to get background color from current theme programmatically

Tags: android

I tried something like this, but i stuck:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue(); 
if (this.parentActivity.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.windowBackground, typedValue, true))
{
  // how to get color?
}
```

Comment: at xml android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"

Comment: I tested and determined that `?android:attr/colorBackground` corresponds to the `styles.xml` item `<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/yourColorHere</item>`.

Comment: @ademar111190 this should be the answer!!!!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can get the background color (or Drawable) from the current theme by:

```
TypedValue a = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.windowBackground, a, true);
if (a.isColorType()) {
    // windowBackground is a color
    int color = a.data;
} else {
    // windowBackground is not a color, probably a drawable
    Drawable d = activity.getResources().getDrawable(a.resourceId);
}
```

[isColorType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue#isColorType()) was introduced in API level 29. Before then, you can use the following instead:

```
if (a.type >= TypedValue.TYPE_FIRST_COLOR_INT && a.type <= TypedValue.TYPE_LAST_COLOR_INT)
```

Comment: Great answer.  In case anyone else is tripped up by this, on Xamarin you have to use Resource.Attribute.primaryAccentColor instead of, for instance, Resource.Styleable.MyTheme_primaryAccentColor.  This probably applies to Android native development too.  That is, reference the attr file/object instead of the theme directly.  I don't understand the difference, but the latter seems like it would be the right choice but was NOT.

Comment: pbarranis, When defining a style xml, most of my colors are referenced with unqualified names (`<item name="someColor>`) and are declared in my own `attrs.xml`; but the background color is qualified (`<item name="android:background">`), and it's declared in the Android system somewhere, not in my own `attrs.xml`, like the others. Therefore, the background color is not a property of *my* app, but a property of *any/every* android app. That's the reason for the difference.

Comment: @ashuhes FYI, I updated your answer to use the latest API function, `isColorType`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @jpaugh Good to know! Thanks for updating it.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the resources of your Theme by using :

```
TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.ThemeName, new int[] {R.attr.attribute_name});     
int attributeResourceId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
```

Comment: I tried this: TypedArray a = this.parentActivity.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(android.R.attr.windowBackground, new int[] {android.R.attr.windowBackground});     
      int attributeResourceId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
      
      int aaa = this.parentActivity.getResources().getColor(attributeResourceId); but this is not working. I get exception.

Comment: Oh! What exception do you get ?

Comment: 09-12 12:05:34.864: E/AndroidRuntime(32137): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 12:05:34.864: E/AndroidRuntime(32137): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/screen_background_selector_light.xml from color state list resource ID #0x10804a8
09-12 12:05:34.864: E/AndroidRuntime(32137):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java)
09-12 12:05:34.864: E/AndroidRuntime(32137):  at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java)...

Comment: There would be a line `Caused by: ` in your log cat. Could you please mention that ? It lets you the exact place of error.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/screen_background_selector_light.xml from color state list resource ID #0x10804a8
 at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java)
 at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java)
 at com.mycustomapp.NewsDetailsFragment.onCreateView(NewsDetailsFragment.java:64)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
 at

Comment: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at

Comment: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #18: <item> tag requires a 'android:color' attribute.
 at android.content.res.ColorStateList.inflate(ColorStateList.java)
 at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java)
 at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXml(ColorStateList.java)
 ... 17 more

Comment: It says that in the Binary XML file at line 18, the <item> tag is missing `android:color` attribute.

Answer (score 6):

for your qoustion the easiest way is:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue(); 
if (this.parentActivity.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.windowBackground, typedValue, true))
{
  // how to get color?
  int colorWindowBackground = typedValue.data;// **just add this line to your code!!**
}
```