# Get background color of a Layout

Tags: android, background-color

I want to find the background color of a Layout from my code. Is there any way to find it? something like `linearLayout.getBackgroundColor()`?

Comment: Since the background may not be a color, you can use linearLayout.getBackground() which will give you a `Drawable`. There is no API to get background color, specifically. [Read more in the docs for View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getBackground%28%29)

Comment: But I really need to find the color of a layout. There should be some other way ! or is it possible to get it from `Drawable`?

Comment: Why are you not [pulling the background color from the theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14468034/712526)?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

This can only be accomplished in API 11+ if your background is a solid color.

```
int color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
Drawable background = view.getBackground();
if (background instanceof ColorDrawable)
    color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();
```

Comment: I was just going to edit my answer and say that specifically that might work! However, I am not sure why there's an API 11+ restriction? `ColorDrawable` seems to be available since API 1, and also view.getBackground().

Comment: Nevermind. I see that `.getColor` for ColorDrawable was added in API 11.

Comment: You could convert the `Drawable` to a `Bitmap` and get the first pixel. `int color = bitmap.getPixel(0, 0);`

Comment: I used this `((ColorDrawable) row.getBackground()).getColor()` as `(row.background as ColorDrawable).color`  but i faced with this error `android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable`

Answer (score 19):

To get background color of a Layout:

```
LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay1);
ColorDrawable viewColor = (ColorDrawable) lay.getBackground();
int colorId = viewColor.getColor();
```

If It is RelativeLayout then just find its id and use there object instead of LinearLayout.

Comment: Is there any reason against using ViewGroup (or even View) instead all it's possible sub classes to get the background?

Answer (score 13):

ColorDrawable.getColor() will only work with API level above 11, so you can use this code to support it from API level 1. Use reflection below API level 11.

```
public static int getBackgroundColor(View view) {
        Drawable drawable = view.getBackground();
        if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
            ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) drawable;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
                return colorDrawable.getColor();
            }
            try {
                Field field = colorDrawable.getClass().getDeclaredField("mState");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object object = field.get(colorDrawable);
                field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField("mUseColor");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                return field.getInt(object);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Short and Simple way:

```
int color = ((ColorDrawable)view.getBackground()).getColor();
```

Answer (score 7):

For kotlin fans

```
fun View.getBackgroundColor() = (background as? ColorDrawable?)?.color ?: Color.TRANSPARENT
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are cases where background might not a `ColorDrawable` so we need to check it before the cast:

```kotlin
 if (view.background is ColorDrawable) {
     val bgColor = (view.background as ColorDrawable).color
 }
```