# How to check a view's background color ? (API < 13)

Tags: android

I have a layout with different views.
One of the views has a background color set to `android.R.color.holo_green_light`

Inside a click handler, how can I check if the clicked element has a background set to `android.R.color.holo_green_light` ?

I know for for APIs > 13 I can get `view.getBackground().getColor()`, but how to do it for APIs below 13 ?

Comment: Hi, I don't if it can help but this solution is avalaible from API 11 which maybe lower as the one you're using (you did not specified) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14779461/2545832

Comment: View.getBackground() returns a Drawable. There is no method getColor() for Drawable.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the background of the view is a Color.

You can get the drawable and cast it to a ColorDrawable:

```
ColorDrawable viewColor = (ColorDrawable) view.getBackground();
int colorId = viewColor.getColor();
```

That works on Android API 11