# How to get the color of view background in hexadecimal?

Tags: android, colors

How to get the color of view. If there isn't any way please write the code for it.

Comment: Do you have the color available in any form?

Comment: Refer this link for it http://stackoverflow.com/a/6540378/3946958  ..Before asking the question here ,plz search about the topic properly

Comment: how do you set the color of view, android:background?

Comment: Not sure if your are asking for something like this: [Get background color of a Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14779461/1113211)

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I search but I didn't find any answer so I asked here.

Comment: @TangKe I set it with view.setBackgroundColor

Answer (score 0):

If you use `view.setBackgroundColor()` method to set the color of view,
view will auto create a `ColorDrawable` instance to set to the view,
you just need to call `int color = ((ColorDrawable)view.getBackground()).getColor()` to retrieve the color. 
If you want to get the color value in hexadecimal format, just invoke 'Integer.toHexString(color)'

hope this can help you