# Get color of TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, uitextview

I set color of my TextView randomly. I have array String[] colors  = {"BLUE", "RED", "GREEN", "BLACK", "YELLOW", "GRAY"}. I need to check if color of my TextView in this array and return index. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

First get the text (or [background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779259/get-background-color-of-a-layout)) color from your `TextView`. Then simply iterate over your list of colors (*not* color names) and return the index when you find a match.

When you use `List` instead of an array the `indexOf()` function already does this for you.

```
int textColor = textView.getCurrentTextColor();
List<Integer> colors = Arrays.asList(Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK, Color.YELLOW, Color.GRAY);
int index = colors.indexOf(textColor);
```