# Android default white background hex code

Tags: java, android, xml, colors, hex

What is the hex code for the default white background that is given to layouts when you create a new project?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked in another Stack Exchenge network, or researched tools or ways to achieve the non-programming related need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14468034/1549476) shows you to get the default background color.

To summarize, just do something like this

```
TypedValue a = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.windowBackground, a, true);
int color = a.data;
```

Then `color` will contain the value. This might be useful because the background might be different across different platforms (as [the javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Light) mentions, you can only count on the background being light).

Comment: The `color` variable will contain the correct hex code (albeit in the form of an integer rather than a String). If you just want the hex code of the image you posted, I suggest using the "paint test" tool in an image manipulation system to give you the value.