# Get a style's windowBackground attribute

Tags: android, android-styles

Let's say I have this theme :

```
<style name="DummyTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Now in my activity I want to get this style's text color and `android:windowBackground` color propety. I already have this code (the default colors are for debugging purposes) :

```
TypedArray rootStyle = obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.DummyStyle, new int[]{android.R.attr.textColor, android.R.attr.windowBackground});

@ColorInt int textColor = rootStyle.getColor(0, Color.CYAN);
@ColorInt int backgroundColor = rootStyle.getColor(1, Color.MAGENTA);

rootStyle.recycle();
```

It works for the text color, but not for the background color :`backgroundColor` is set to `-1`. Not `Color.MAGENTA`, but `-1`.

I also tried to get a `ColorDrawable` out of it instead of a color integer but it doesn't work either (its color is set to `-1`).

Why ? Thanks !

Comment: Cannot find a method with [such a signature](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html). What overload of `obtainStyledattributes` are you using?

Comment: It's `public final TypedArray obtainStyledAttributes(@StyleRes int resid, @StyleableRes int[] attrs)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375766/how-to-get-background-color-from-current-theme-programmatically